# How to Remove the MvvmCross Messenger Subscriptions

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross for my Xamarin.Android Application.  I am using Messenger for Communication between my Service and ViewModel.  **Eg**: HomeViewModel has a Subscription for ItemRefresh Method. I used to Publish from Service for any change in Items.  Below is the example code snippet.

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
 private MvxSubscriptionToken _updatedItemToken;
 public HomeViewModel()
 {
    _updatedItemToken = messenger.Subscribe<UpdatedItemMessage>(ItemUpdated);
 }
 public void ItemUpdated(UpdatedItemMessage message)
 {
    //my code to refresh the page.
 }
}
```

**What is the Problem now?**

Everything is working fine until I Introduce logout feature.
During Logout, Irrespective of where you are in the app, I need to clear all the activities from navigation stack and navigate to login page

After Logout,  If I goes to HomeViewModel, The Subscription added again and the messages doubled up (hitting twice on each publish message).

**What I have tried?**

1. Purge the Subscription On Logging out. using _messenger.RequestPurgeAll();
2. Tried purging individual message like below

> if(_messenger.HasSubscriptionsFor())
>       {
>       messenger.RequestPurge(typeof(UpdatedItemMessage));
>       }

3. Unsubscribe the Message OnDestroy().  It works well on navigations of the page but not during logout.  Logout will clear all activities immediately which will not call OnDestroy of every Visible Activities.  Logout code is below.

> var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginView));
>   intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
>   StartActivity(intent); Finish();

Any help would be appreciated? I don't understand the use of RequestPurge which should ideally help for me but not.

Comment: A clean design is that each Page has a list of subscription tokens, created (Subscribe) when page appears, and destroyed (Unsubscribe) when page disappears. `override` the appropriate page methods to do so. Then at Logout, simply pop the pages from nav stack - they each unsubscribe their own tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disposing the `MvxSubscriptionToken` you get from the messenger?

In your case:

```
_updatedItemToken.Dispose();
```

This should make the subscription go away.

Comment: Thank you, However the main problem is "In one point of time say logout, I used to clear all the activity stack and move to login activity".  In this particular usecase, how can i dispose the token.  since, ondestroy won't call for all activities in navigation stack.